# Any way to stop the poster destroying this question?

Tags: discussion

The Op keeps removing this post :

```
https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/52906/10902
```

Can it be locked?

Comment: I was aware of the deletion earlier, but I was reluctant to act earlier - the locking apparently is considered pretty much last resort. Anyway, my reasoning was to let the other - more experienced - moderators to defuse the situation.  I thought that if I took more direct action, I would have inflamed the situation further, because indirectly I started it.

Comment: @NMech Thanks for locking it. If it stays stable now that is good.

Comment: one of the other moderators also contacted the user privately so we should be ok for now.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been locked.

I don't know how quickly it was locked after you posted this, but in the future it may be quicker to raise a flag on the question.